# Java String insertion to MySQL field of type MEDIUMTEXT

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

I'm taking a string and inserting it into a mySQL database field of type MEDIUMTEXT. When I print it out, there is a bunch of '-' characters and whitespace surrounding a slightly corrupted version of my original text. Am I doing this wrong?

```
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");  
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/tripDB?characterEncoding=utf8","root","pass");   
Statement stmt = con.createStatement(); 
query = "insert into trip (name, date, details) values (?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement preparedStmt = con.prepareStatement(query);
preparedStmt.setString(1, name); //Inserts correctly (varchar)
preparedStmt.setString(2, date); //Correct (varchar)
preparedStmt.setString(3, details); //Corrupted (MEDIUMTEXT)
preparedStmt.execute();
con.close();
```

Comment: Have tried by removing characterEncoding=utf8 from connection string ?

Comment: You should also be using `preparedStmt.executeUpdate();`. Check the collations of your database and tables, make sure they are all UTF-8. If thats the case then check if there is any data that in `details` that may need to be encoded.